# Multiple connections in a single SSH SOCKS 5 Proxy

Tags: proxy, ssh, socks

My fist question here on Stackoverflow: **What should I need to do so that the SSH SOCKS 5 Proxy (SSH2) will allow multiple connections?**

What I have noticed, is that when I load a page in Firefox (already configured to use the SOCKS 5 proxy), it loads everything one by one. It can be perceived by bare eyes, and I also confirm that through the use of Firebug's NET tab, which logs the connections that have been made.

I have already configure some of the directives in the *about:config* page, like pipeline, persistent proxy connections, and a few other things. But I still get this kind of sequential load of resources, which is noticeably very slow.

```
network.http.pipelining;true
network.http.pipelining.maxrequests;8
network.http.pipelining.ssl;true
network.http.proxy.pipelining;true
network.http.max-persistent-connections-per-proxy;100
network.proxy.socks_remote_dns;true
```

My ISP sucks because during the day, it intentionally breaks connections on a random basis. And so, it is impossible to actually accomplish meaningful works without the need of a lot of browser refresh or hitting F5 key. So, that is why I started to find solutions to this.

The SSH's dynamic port forwarding is the best solution I find to date, because it has some pretty good compression which saves a lot of useless traffic, and is also secure. The only thing remaining is to get it to have multiple connections running in it.

Thanks for all the inputs.

Comment: There is nothing about the socks protocol that would cause this behaviour. It is more likely a result of http pipelining or less likely a awkward proxy implementation.

Comment: Pipelining says only, that it can send all the request over the same TCP connection without waiting for the first response. Not all proxies work with pipelining, but from what I understand you don't connect to a http proxy at all, but instead use a socks server which is a different thing.

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same thoughts and my conclusion is that it should already have multiple connections going through the socks proxy. This is because if you view the ssh connection with `-vvv` flag, you'll notice it opening up different ports for the different requests.

Answer (score 0):

I think it may have something to do with SSH-over-TCP itself; plus, perhaps, some extra inefficiencies and/or bugs in the implementations.  Are you using only OpenSSH on Mac OS X / *BSD / Linux, or is this PuTTY on Windows?

Your situation is actually pretty much exactly why SCTP was developed (as a TCP replacement), which has a notion of multiple streams from within a single connection.

Hopefully, we'll have SSH over SCTP readily available one day.  The best part about SCTP is that it'd still work over IPv4, i.e. it is supposedly mostly a matter of only the endhosts having support for it, so, unlike IPv6, you wouldn't have to wait for your lazy ISP (at leasts, theoretically).

Comment: Another issue is that each domain name resolution is blocking the rest of the flow (see http://superuser.com/questions/700453/forwarded-connection-refused-by-server-administratively-prohibited-open-failed), so, your setting of `network.proxy.socks_remote_dns;true` might actually be backfiring.